# Videos much too slow on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, video

I have purchased my first Raspberry Pi, the Zero W for a media application. The application requires the Pi to play normal 1080p Videos at a reasonable frame rate (anything around 25 - 30 FPS). I have read on several occasions that this should not be a problem on the Zero W.
However, with a clean Raspbian Desktop installation, the mp4 Files I have play at around 4 to 5 FPS using VLC Player. I have increased the GPU memory from 64MB to 128MB, but this does not seem to make a difference. I cannot use omxplayer with my current installation because it is not supported anymore in Raspbian Bullseye.
Here is a screenshot of the media info of the video file.

[image: Media Info of my video file]

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome. You could look into recoding the videos; it's (apparently, I have not done it) possible to keep the same frame rate while reducing the actual data bitrate, eg: https://codecalamity.com/raspberry-pi-hardware-encoding-speed-test/  See 3rd paragraph about MJPEG streams.  You might also recode them as H.264, as I do not think the hardware acceleration applies to .mp4 files.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to the Raspberry's world, but some people suggest to increment clock frequency on Pi Zero W from 700 MHz to 1GHz

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try Raspberry Pi Video Looper.